# android studio can't find ExpandableListConnector

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create a custom `ExpandableListView`, but somehow android studio can't find the class that I need (I get `cannot find symbol class ExpandableListConnector`). At first I thought that it might be missing, but then I checked out Sdk\sources\android-23\android\widget folder and it was there. I tried to clean and rebuild, but got no luck with that.

Here's a sample:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

//Here I get the error
import android.widget.ExpandableListConnector;


public class AnimatedExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
Context mContext;

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public boolean expandGroup(int groupPos) {
    return expandGroup(groupPos, true);
}
```

}

Comment: Obviously, this class is not a part of public api.

Comment: So there's no way I can use it?

Comment: Other than copy the source code and use it? No...

Comment: Is that a good practice or I should avoid it?